# Why wont my code switch back and forth between lists?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, methods, pygame

I have two lists in my game that I want to switch between in my method.

I am working on a game where at a certain point, if a box is broken, a color is printed on the screen - those colors show up in a particular order, and are in a list. There are 3 levels: A, B, and C. I have this set up so that the levels switch one the player's health reaches a certain point. I want the lists to switch each time a new level begins. So if Level A starts in List A, I want level B to switch to list B and level C to switch back to list A.

I don't know why my code isn't working. I have "if" statements that are contingent on the player health, but the switch isn't happening.

In this code boxes are broken by 'shards'. BoxA and BoxB are lists. What I thought would happen is that when the player's health was less than 20, BoxA would be used. When the player's health is above 20, Box B should be used. When health is above 40, BoxA should be used again.

```
    hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.boxs, self.shards, False, True)
    hit_count = 0

    for hit in hits:
        font1 = pg.font.SysFont('comicsans', 100)
        if BOXA[hit_count] == GRE:
            text = font1.render('green', 1, (GREEN))
            #self.effects_sounds['lose_sound'].play()
        elif BOXA[hit_count] == BLU:
            text = font1.render('blue', 1, (CYAN))
        elif BOXB[hit_count] == YEL:
            text = font1.render('yellow', 1, (YELLOW))
        elif BOXB[hit_count] == RE:
            text = font1.render('red', 1, (RED))
            #self.effects_sounds['jackpot_sound'].play()

        self.screen.blit(text, (250 -(text.get_width()/2),200))
        pg.display.update()
        i = 0
        while i < 100:
            pg.time.delay(10)
            i += 1
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    i = 301
                    pg.quit()
        hit.health -= SHARD_DAMAGE
        if self.player.health < 20:
            self.player.health += 0
            hit.health += BOXA.popleft()
            hit_count += 1
            print('lvl_A')

        if self.player.health > 20 and self.player.health < 40:
            hit.health += BOXB.popleft()
            self.player.health += 0
            print('lvl_B')

        elif self.player.health > 40:
            self.player.health += 0
            hit.health += BOXA.popleft()
            print('lvl_C')
```

The lists are defined in a separate file that I import into the main code. Here is an example list:

```
BOXA =  deque([BLU, GRE, BLU, BLU, GRE, GRE, GRE, BLU, GRE, BLU, BLU, BLU])
BOXB = deque([YEL, YEL, RE, YEL, RE, RE, RE, YEL])
#BLU = 1
#GRE = 2
#YEL = 7
#RE = 4
```

I'm really not sure why it isn't switching, so any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: use `print(message)` to see which part of code is used and to display values in varaibles. Maybe there are different values then you expect or you have wrong indentations and some code is never used.

Comment: Quibble: what happens when `self.player.health` *equals* 20 ?

Comment: what should happen when it goes to level B ? Should it display text in different color ? You don't check level when you display text so it always display from `BoxA` which is first on `if/elif` - `if BOXA[hit_count] == GRE:`. Maybe better use variable `level = 'B'` and check it when you display text. OR use variable `box = BOXA` and when you change level then set `box = BOXB` and later use `if box[hit_count] == GRE:`

Comment: @Kingsley I gave that a try - it just ignored the other levels - there was no change when it was greater than or equal to 20; making it only equal 20 made it not switch levels.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point - the code only ever checks `> 20` and `< 20`.  One of those checks should (probably) have a `<=` / `>=` somewhere.

Comment: @furas that second suggestion did it! Please post your box variable suggestion - I'll make it the official answer - thank you!

Comment: @Kingsley think I understand what you're saying now. I'll go through my code and add that to some other places as will - thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question but I see one problem in code

You should set variable

```
level = "A"
```

and change it

```
    if self.player.health < 20:
        level = "A"

    if self.player.health > 20 and self.player.health < 40:
        level = "B"

    elif self.player.health > 40:
        level = "C"
```

and use it when you display color

```
if level in ("A", "C"):
    if BOXA[hit_count] == GRE:
        text = font1.render('green', 1, (GREEN))
    elif BOXA[hit_count] == BLU:
        text = font1.render('blue', 1, (CYAN))
else:
    elif BOXB[hit_count] == YEL:
        text = font1.render('yellow', 1, (YELLOW))
    elif BOXB[hit_count] == RE:
        text = font1.render('red', 1, (RED))
```

Without this it always check first list `BOXA` and it always find color which it uses to display text and it never check `BOXB`

---

OR you should use

```
box = BOXA
```

and change it

```
if self.player.health < 20:
    box = BOXA

if self.player.health > 20 and self.player.health < 40:
    box = BOXB

elif self.player.health > 40:
    box = BOXA
```

and use it

```
    if box[hit_count] == GRE:
        text = font1.render('green', 1, (GREEN))
    elif box[hit_count] == BLU:
        text = font1.render('blue', 1, (CYAN))
    elif box[hit_count] == YEL:
        text = font1.render('yellow', 1, (YELLOW))
    elif box[hit_count] == RE:
        text = font1.render('red', 1, (RED))
```

---

BTW: you could create list or dictionary with colors

```
all_colors = {
     GRE: (GREEN, "green")
     BLU: (CYAN, "blue")
     ...
}
```

and select color using this dictionary instead of `if/elif`

```
color, name = all_colors[ box[hit_count] ]
text = font1.render(name, 1, color)
```